# differential equation contains definite integral

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals

I am stuck on solving the following differential equation which contains a definite integral that I don't know how to deal with:

$$ f^{\prime\prime} + a^2 f - b\int_0^L f(t) \, dt = c$$

The boundary condition is $f(0)=0$ and $f(L)=R$. Anyone help me out of here? Thank you in advance.

Comment: $$
f^{\prime\prime}(t) + a^2 f(t) - b\int_0^L f(t) \, dt = c
$$
It's a bit confusing to use the same letter, $t,$ to refer both to the independent variable in the differential equation and to the bound variable of integration. So let's write this as
$$
f^{\prime\prime}(t) + a^2 f(t) - b\int_0^L f(u) \, du = c.
$$
This says
$$
f''(t) + a^2 f(t) = \text{constant}
$$
but then it also says something about that "constant", and "constant" means not depending on the independent variable $t.$

Comment: @MichaelHardy : $f_p=Ct^2+Dt+E$ gives $f_p''+a^2f_p=2C+a^2Ct^2+a^2Dt+a^2E$, which is not constant.

Comment: Any development from there? I think the equation it's under the category "integro-differential equation"

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\int_0^L f(t) dt$ is a constant depending on $L$ and call it $d$. Now you just need to integrate twice. I write $f(t)$ as $f$.

$$f' \frac{df'}{df}=c+bd-a^2f$$

Comment: The last step is an unnecessary complication. The oscillation equation $f''+a^2f=k$ can be solved with standard methods.

Comment: Good point. Thanks a lot

Comment: I do not know if that method is correct. It is not clear that the function obtained will satisfy the relation given by the first equation with the integral. (since the constant described as $d$ in this post is in fact a function of $f$ )

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is $$f(t)=A\cos(at)+B\sin(at)+C$$ where the boundary conditions and the original equation lead to 3 linear equations in the 3 parameters $A,B,C$,
\begin{align}
0&=f(0)=A+C\\
R&=f(L)=A\cos(aL)+B\sin(aL)+C\\
c&=a^2C-b\left(\frac Aa\sin(AL)+\frac Ba(1-\cos(aL))+CL\right)
\end{align}
 This linear system might be without solution, but then the problem is not solvable for the given boundaries and boundary conditions.